# run command and make sure it ends before continuing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

i am running a command line program from inside my c# code behind page. the command looks like so.

```
String runMe = baseDir + @"Bin\ffmpeg.exe"; 
String convertVideo = " -i \"" + fullFileName + "\"  -ab 64 -ar 44100 -b 200 -y -f flv  \"" + fullFileNameWOextension + ".flv\" ";
String makeImages = " -i \"" + fullFileName + "\" -r 1 -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:15 -f image2 -s 120x96 \"" + imagesPath + "" + filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf(".")) + "_images%05d.jpeg\"";
EdgeCastHelper.ExecuteCommandSync(runMe, convertVideo);
EdgeCastHelper.ExecuteCommandSync(runMe, makeImages);
```

There are some bits missing which are passed in as parameters. Once i have converted the video i upload it to separate file server.

What i would like to know: Is there a way to stop the upload process happening until the exe has run its course, ie fully converted the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have access to change the EdgeCastHelper.ExecuteCommandSync method, but there is a [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method.

Comment: Yeah i have access to that method. Thanks heaps. It is just what i was after.